# Procedure for finding domain of algebraically Combined Functions and algebraically Combined Functions

Tags: functions, algorithms

I was *interested in:

> A Procedure for finding the domain of $\color{green}{\text{algebraically combined functions}}$ and $\color{green}{\text{algebraically combined functions}}.$

Assignment Questions [already Submitted]

Given

- $f(x)=\sqrt{1-2x}$
- $g(x)=\frac{x}{x^2-1}$

Find the domain of

- $\Large\frac fg$

  My Answer

> $(-\infty, 1) \;\cup\;(-1,0) \;\cup\;(0,\frac12]$

- $\large gf^2$

  My Answer

> $(-\infty, -1) \;\cup\;(-1,\frac12]$

I was told that answers are incorrect, but from my understanding
the domain of algebraically combined functions is the intersection of the functions domain. Is it?

If someone could help clear up my confusion, that would be great.
And, if possible, any clear, procedural methods for finding the domain of a composition of functions and algebraically combined functions or, better yet, a link/suggested reading that is clear and intuitive for finding the domain.

Comment: I think I understand your dilemma: if $g$ is not defined at $-1$, how could ever $\frac fg$ be defined at $-1$. Based on this, your solution seems correct (at first glance).  However, it seems, they wanted you to first do the algebraic manipulations, and *then* determine the domain *of the received formula*. As these examples show, this is indeed a different question.

Comment: This seems correct. I suppose the only way of knowing would be to directly ask the instructor ahead of time. Oh well. At least I know my logic wasn't incorrect had I understood the question the way I did.

Comment: the function $\frac{f}{g}$ is defined at -1 as it is reciprocal of g. Also, it is unclear whether it is $gf^2(x)$ or $g(x)[f(x)]^2$. Please verify from the source which of these applies as this might be the cause of the incorrectness of the solutions.